# How to configure Jenkins to launch a job on it's startup without using UI manual configuration

Tags: jenkins, jcasc

I want to implement a healthcheck(invoking an endpoint) in Jenkins, which should run in docker container.
I don't want to manually configure my pipeline job in Jenkins every time container is up.

I've tried **[JCasC](https://jenkins.io/projects/jcasc/)**, but it doesn't allow to autoconfigure jobs.

How do I **automatically configure jobs on first Jenkins launch** and **trigger them on each time Jenkins is up**?

Comment: probably with this plugin: https://plugins.jenkins.io/startup-trigger-plugin

Comment: The [Startup Trigger](https://plugins.jenkins.io/startup-trigger-plugin) plugin mentioned by @lvthillo alongside the [Job DSL](https://plugins.jenkins.io/job-dsl) plugin should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Here's is an example `jobs` section of `jenkins.yml` (CasC config file); it requires the "Job DSL" and "Startup Trigger" plugins (in addition to the "Configuration as Code" plugin, of course):

```
jobs:
  - script: >
      pipelineJob("Deploy Local2 Stack") {
        description()
        keepDependencies(false)
        triggers {
          hudsonStartupTrigger {
            nodeParameterName("master")
            label("master")
            quietPeriod("0")
            runOnChoice("False")
          }
        }
        definition {
          cpsScm {
            scm {
              git {
                remote {
                  url("https://myrepo/mystuff.git")
                  credentials("scm")
                }
                branch("master")
              }
            }
            scriptPath("pipeline/main/Jenkinsfile")
          }
        }
        disabled(false)
      }
```

The `triggers` section is what's important; the rest is just to put it in context.

Apparently, the startup trigger can also work on slave nodes but I gather that's not what you want, so I specified `master`.

Note: This is the kernel from which I pieced together the solution: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41671?focusedCommentId=287026&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-287026

Answer (score 0):

Could you please tell me where you can see all the plugins that can be installed using jcasc? Or where to get the plugins you talked about

Comment: Installing plugins is one of the things you do outside of jcasc.